# passing static image to react native community slider with @2x suffix

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have been having an issue that the image i am passing to the thumbImage in the slider is having different sizes on different android devices, it's too big on some of them 
so i decided to pass the image using the @2x and @3x suffix to to provide images for different screen densities

however i am not sure how to use it in that case

here's part of my code

there are the imports

```
import HandleActiveIcon from './img/handle-active.png';
import HandleIcon from './img/handle.png';
```

the props being passed to the slider

```
const Slider = ({
  minimumTrackTintColor = colors.primary,
  maximumTrackTintColor = 'transparent',
  minimumTrackTintColorActive = colors.secondary,
  maximumTrackTintColorActive = 'transparent',
  minimumValue = 0,
  maximumValue = 100,
  initialValue,
  thumbTintColor = colors.secondary,
  thumbTintColorActive = colors.primary,

  thumbImage = HandleIcon,
  thumbImageActive = HandleActiveIcon,

  onSlidingStart = () => {},
  onSlidingComplete = () => {},
  onValueChange = () => {},
  throttleTime = 100,
  step = 10,
}
```

and that's the slider component

```
 <SliderComponent
      style={style.slider}
      minimumValue={minimumValue}
      maximumValue={maximumValue}
      minimumTrackTintColor={
        isActive ? minimumTrackTintColorActive : minimumTrackTintColor
      }
      maximumTrackTintColor={
        isActive ? maximumTrackTintColorActive : maximumTrackTintColor
      }
      thumbImage={isActive ? thumbImageActive : thumbImage}
      value={initialValue}
      onSlidingStart={handleSlidingStart}
      onSlidingComplete={handleSlidingComplete}
      onValueChange={handleValueChange}
      step={step}
    />
```

i did follow this folder model

```
.
├── slider.js
└── img
    ├── HandleIcon.png
    ├── HandleIcon@2x.png
    └── HandleIcon@3x.png
```

not sure how to handle it after that?

any ideas ?

thank you